# Draw series of images along with straight line between touches using Cocos2D

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make series of images along with the path that between the points touch begins and ends.

So, I tried CCRibbon, it makes series of images along with touches, but I can't reduce the gap between images.

Actually I want to make no gaps or overlapping images.

Then, I tried another example using CCRenderTaxture, it makes beautifully what I want,

BUT it makes gap too when touch moves fast.

So, for me, it becomes very very hard problem.

Is there Anybody has advice for it or an example.

I really appreciate.

Comment: if you move you fingers fast enough you get 2 distant touch points, you need to check the distance between 2 consecutive touches and add stuff between the 2 points, ccpMidpoint(<#const CGPoint v1#>, <#const CGPoint v2#>) and ccpDistance(<#const CGPoint v1#>, <#const CGPoint v2#>) can come in handy